# How do I convert a binary file to a byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, arrays, file-conversion

Given the path of a file (e.g. "C:\MyPicture.jpg"), how do I convert a binary file into a byte array?

I know I have a lot of .NET objects at my disposal, such as `BinaryReader`, `FileStream`, `StreamReader`, and others, but I'm not sure of the best method to take a binary file and convert it into `byte[]`.  How might this be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [`File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\MyPicture.jpg")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\MyPicture.jpg");
```